# What does the algorithm calculate?

Tags: algorithms, correctness-proof, loop-invariants

We have the following

```
i <- 0 
j <- 0 
x <- 1 
y <- 1 
z <- 1 
c <- 1 
u <- 1 
while i<n do 
   i <- i+1 
   j <- i 
   x <- x*i 
   z <- x 
   y <- i+1 
   y <- x*y 
   while j<2*i do 
      j <- j+1 
      z <- z*j 
   od 
   c <- z div (x*y) 
od
```

I want to find the loop invariant for both while-loops.

I applied the algorithm some times to understand what it does:

The inner while loop calculates the following: $$z=z\prod_{m=1}^{2i-1}(i+m)=x\prod_{m=1}^{2i-1}(i+m)$$ or not? Is this also the loop invariant of the inner while loop?

So I got the following results:

First loop:

```
i=1 
j=i=1 
x=1 
z=x=1 
y=i+1=2 
y=x*y=2 
inner while loop: z=x(i+1)=2 
c = z div (x*y) = 2 div 2 = 1
```

Second loop:

```
i=2 
j=i=2 
x=1*2=2 
z=x=2 
y=i+1=3 
y=x*y=2*3=6 
inner while loop: z=x(i+1)(i+2)(i+3)=2*3*4*5 
c = z div (x*y) = 2*3*4*5/2*6=10
```

Third loop:

```
i=3 
j=i=3 
x=2*3=6 
z=x=6
y=i+1=4 
y=x*y=24 
inner while loop: z=x(i+1)(i+2)(i+3)(i+4)(i+5)=6*4*5*6*7*8 
c = z div (x*y) = 6*4*5*6*7*8/6*24=5*7*8=280
```

Is everything correct? But what exactly calculates the algorithm? What is a general formula of the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $x=i!$. Now it's easy to see $y=(i+1)!$ and $z=(2i)!$. So $c=\frac{(2i)!}{i!(i+1)!}$, which is the $i$th [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

P.S. Your formula is wrong. The condition of the inner loop is $j=i+m\le2i$, so $m$ is from $1$ to $i$ instead of $2i-1$ or something.

Comment: Ah I got it now!! So the algorithm computes the $n$th Catalan number,  right? Is the loop invariant of the inner loop the $z=(2i)!$ and of the outer loop $c=\frac{(2i)!}{i!(i+1)!}$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Right. More precisely, I would say it computes the first $n$ Catalan number since $c$ is computed inside the loop (which is not necessary if you only need the $n$th). But if you are considering loop invariant, I guess it should be $z=j!$ of the inner loop since $z=(2i)!$ only holds after the termination. For the outer loop, those $x,y,z,c$ equations are all loop invariants and I think $x=i!$ is the most critical one in the sense of induction.